# Что за проблема с импортом пакета?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Импортирую пакет  `import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';`, при импорте возникает ошибка:

[image: ошибка]
пакет: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client
Что за ошибка, что она означает?

Comment: наверное проблема в том что пакет для сервера, а вы судя по тегам используете его в реакт приложении:)

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин Ну да, а как его заюзать? я могу в реакте получить из nodejs что-нибудь?

Comment: Можете получить. Но всё ж таки придётся понять что некоторые вещи можно делать только сервере.